# Amount of Liquid in Container

Tags: physics, applications

Given:

- a cuboid container, of dimensions *h* into *w* into *l*
- a rate of flow of liquid per unit time through an inlet, *in*
- a rate of flow of liquid per unit time from an outlet, *out*, **when the container is full**

How would we find the amount of liquid in the container after time *t*?

This sort of problem is often found in middle school math textbooks, where the approach is "if the container empties in three hours, then a third of the container empties in one hour" but this is obviously wrong as the container empties fast at first but slows down as it does so.

Comment: So do you have a function which expresses the outlet flow rate in terms of depth of liquid or something similar ? Do we assume that the inlet flow is constant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show by applying the Bernoulli's Theorem that the volume output rate at anytime is

$out_{x} = -A \sqrt{x}$

Here, $x$ is the vertical distance from the water surface to the outlet. $A$ is a constant depending on the physical parameters of the system. The constant can be determined in terms of the given full container flow rate $out_{max}$.

You can show the volume output to be:

$out_{x}=out_{max}\sqrt{\frac{x}{h}}$

The volume input is always $in$

We can write a differential equation:
$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{d(wlx)}{dt}= in- out_{max}\sqrt{\frac{x}{h}}$

If you integrate and find an expression for the height of water $x$ as a function of $t$, you are done